# Message: mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am new to PHP MVC CI and

**I am getting below error.**

> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: No such host is known.

**Below is my info being passed.**

> hostname:http://localhost:1234/Sample/
>
> username:root
>
> password:  //here Password is blank
>
> database:codeignitordb
>
> port:1234

**Function**

```
$mysqli->real_connect($hostname, 
                      $this->username, 
                      $this->password, 
                      $this->database, 
                      $port, 
                      $socket, 
                      $client_flags);
```

here `$socket` and `$client_flags` are `Null`

## Question: Am I missing something ?

Comment: just put host name as localhost

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hostname should be `localhost` only instead of `http://localhost:1234/Sample/`

## This change should be done in database.config.

Comment: Try remove port:1234, if you to use port need to config `httpd.conf`

Comment: Did you config in `httpd.conf` yet?

Comment: Can you help me here: goo.gl/5z0y7S

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388208/layout-php-is-not-showing-the-header-php-part

Answer (score 3):

Try using `127.0.0.1`

or

```
localhost
```

as your hostname