# Layout.php is not showing the header.php part

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

**I have Html like below.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    </head>
    <body style="background:#F7F7F7;">
        <div class="">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**I divided this html in two PHP files. So.There is `Header.php`. Like Below.**

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>
```

**Layout.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <? include 'header.php';?>

    <body style="background:#F7F7F7;">
        <div class="">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

## Problem

Layout.php is not showing the header.php part.

Comment: Why don't you load views from controller? that way would not need to use include. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with short tags,

```
<?php include 'header.php';?>
```

But i would say, in codeigniter use,

```
$this->load->view("header.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

change this line as

```
<?php include 'header.php';?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the most better way is for loading header and footer is create a views/template_view.php where you load your header and footer that way you do not have to load it every time.

**views/template_view.php**

```
<?php $this->load->view('header');?>

<?php $this->load->view($page);?>

<?php $this->load->view('footer');?>
```

On controller then all you would have to do is

```
public function index() {
   // Would be the name of the view you would like for this function / controller
   $data['page'] = 'somefile_view'; 
   $this->load->view('template_view', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$path = APPPATH.'views/header.php';
<?php include $path; ?>
```

> Codeigniter can call path with `APPPATH`. Its CI predefined varaiable

Answer (score 0):

check your php configuration for short_open_tag = On and also for your file location path.

you can try this one also :

But for codeigniter it is better to use like this : $this->load->view('header.php');