# mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses?

Tags: php, codeigniter, server

I'm using codeigniter and I tried to upload my project using filezilla, note that i put everything perfectly (host, username, password and etc) but this error appeared.

please help me know what does it mean?

mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Message: mysqli::real\_connect(): php\_network\_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358703/message-mysqlireal-connect-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-n)

Comment: it worked only in my localhost. how about if I upload it in filezilla? Should I change the 'hostname' ? thank you

Comment: If you upload your code to other host, yes, you need change database server hostname. And don't forget to check database configuration (e.g.: `skip-external-locking`) and user privileges (Allow connect from hosts).

Comment: Still not working, I did changed the hostname and database name.It says "Failed to parse address "http://18.136.203.72:8081:3306""                                                    http://18.136.203.72:8081:3306 this my hostname. thank you anyway

Comment: Not, that is certainly not your database host name - because it is not even syntactically correct. Having `:8081:3306` at the end is wrong, you can not specify the port twice or two different ports in one go, or whatever that was supposed to mean.